# Cannot solve specific dns record on kubernetes (coredns / nodelocaldns)

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I hit a weird problem with coredns/nodelocaldns, basically I can't resolve a specific dns record for a domain. The record is `www.digicert.com` , it answers correctly tho if I dig with *+tcp* or use *force_tcp* in my nodelocaldns Corefile

```
    .:53 {
        errors
        cache 30
        reload
        loop
        bind 169.254.25.10
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
          force_tcp
        }
        prometheus :9253
    }
```

If I use udp all I'm getting is a timeout error

```
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 www.digicert.com. A: read udp 169.254.25.10:40601->169.254.25.10:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 www.digicert.com. A: read udp k8sworkernode:59755->mycompanyns1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 www.digicert.com. A: read udp 169.254.25.10:52648->169.254.25.10:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 www.digicert.com. A: read udp k8sworkernode:42793->mycompanyns2:53: i/o timeout
```

All the other requests work (dig google.com, even dig digicert.com etc.), and I also have deployed two more (staging) clusters on other subnets and the name get resolved without problems.
I checked udp ports and they are open (remember every other dns request works fine), I rebooted kubernetes nodes...
Below is a tcpdump on a staging cluster where  resolution works ([www.digicert.com](http://www.digicert.com) is a CNAME for 3ivgup7.x.incapdns.net)

```
19:31:42.472765 IP k8snode.55631 > ns2.mycompany: 8824+ [1au] A? 3ivgup7.x.incapdns.net. (63)
19:31:42.474636 IP ns2.mycompany > k8snode.55631: 8824 1/6/43 A 45.60.123.229 (847)
19:31:44.195436 IP k8snode.55631 > ns2.mycompany: 26109+ AAAA? memcache. (26)
19:31:44.195721 IP k8snode.39894 > ns1.mycompany: 44597+ A? memcache. (26)
19:31:44.196073 IP ns2.mycompany > k8snode.55631: 26109 NXDomain 0/1/0 (101)
19:31:44.196507 IP ns1.mycompany > k8snode.39894: 44597 NXDomain 0/1/0 (101)
```

and here on a production cluster where it doesn't

```
19:28:15.860733 IP k8snode.54014 > ns2.mycompany: 10512+ [1au] A? 3ivgup7.x.incapdns.net. (63)
19:28:17.861279 IP k8snode.35119 > ns1.mycompany: 6410+ [1au] A? 3ivgup7.x.incapdns.net. (63)
19:28:17.861307 IP k8snode.59769 > ns2.mycompany: 1440+ NS? . (17)
19:28:17.862230 IP ns2.mycompany > k8snode.59769: 1440 13/0/13 NS i.root-servers.net., NS c.root-servers.net., NS f.root-servers.net., NS b.root-servers.net., NS a.root-servers.net., NS d.root-servers.net., NS j.root-servers.net., NS k.root-servers.net., NS m.root-servers.net., NS l.root-servers.net., NS e.root-servers.net., NS h.root-servers.net., NS g.root-servers.net. (508)
19:28:19.862581 IP k8snode.47932 > ns1.mycompany: 20584+ NS? . (17)
19:28:19.862813 IP k8snode.57677 > ns2.mycompany: 31162+ [1au] A? 3ivgup7.x.incapdns.net. (63)
19:28:19.863374 IP ns1.mycompany > k8snode.47932: 20584 13/0/13 NS l.root-servers.net., NS a.root-servers.net., NS i.root-servers.net., NS h.root-servers.net., NS m.root-servers.net., NS g.root-servers.net., NS d.root-servers.net., NS c.root-servers.net., NS e.root-servers.net., NS f.root-servers.net., NS j.root-servers.net., NS b.root-servers.net., NS k.root-servers.net. (508)
19:28:20.860937 IP k8snode.56137 > ns2.mycompany: 24068+ [1au] A? 3ivgup7.x.incapdns.net. (63)
19:28:21.862959 IP k8snode.39945 > ns1.mycompany: 32140+ [1au] A? 3ivgup7.x.incapdns.net. (63)
19:28:21.863103 IP k8snode.46998 > ns2.mycompany: 40873+ NS? . (17)
```

And that is repeated again and again.
Both cluster have the same /etc/resolv.conf and identical coredns configuration and version. I'm using Antrea if it matters.
I'm a bit lost at the moment...